# R cumulative sum calculation NA issue

Tags: r, na, cumulative-sum

I have been trying to solve a cumulative sum issue for a couple of days and have gotten extremely close, but am still encountering a few problems.

I'm trying to calculate a cumulative sum backwards (from nrow up to the first row) for multiple columns in a data.frame. The code works perfectly when there are no NA/NaN values at the end of the data.frame. But if an NA value is present, the code returns an actual value, when instead I'd like it to return NA. Also, I need the ending value (RBH row in df2) to be present for the last year in which I have a measurement.

Sample measurements for df2:
2009 - 1.2
2010 - 1.8
2011 - NaN
2012 - NaN
RBH - 60.5

Intended Output (would be in df3):
2008 - 57.5
2009 - 58.7
2010 - 60.5
2011 - NaN
2012 - NaN

What my current code gives me for df3:
2008 - 57.5
2009 - 58.7
2010 - 60.5
2011 - 59.5
2012 - 60.5

Code I'm trying:

```
#Build the function to deal with NA values (ex: died in 2010, NA for 2011 & 2012):
cumsum.alt <- function(x){
  res <- NaN*seq(x)
  for(i in seq(x)){
    if(sum(is.na(x[1])) == i){
      res[i] <- i
    } else {
      res[i] <- sum(x[1:i], na.rm=TRUE)
    }
  }
  res
}

#Run function to produce annual radius:
##STILL NEED TO FIX NA ISSUE
df3 <- apply(df2[nrow(df2):1,], 2, function(x) c(x[1], x[1]-cumsum.alt(x[-1])))
df3 <- df3[nrow(df3):1,]
```

Reproducible Data.frame:

```
df2 <- structure(list(AP2D005 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, 1.896, 4.221, 1.204, 1.934, 1.859, 1.575, 1.602, 1.705, 
1.413, 0.786, 1.352, 0.903, 0.821, 1.0855, 1.3375, 1.554, 1.605, 
1.192, 1.395, 1.6965, 1.016, 1.0835, 1.464, 2.0505, 1.719, 2.067, 
2.0025, 1.9245, 2.4895, 2.3465, 2.0105, 0.897, 1.004, 1.6785, 
2.4405, 3.0625, 2.173, 2.629, 3.014, 2.7245, 3.2625, 3.115, 1.515, 
2.632, 2.067, 2.8155, 2.914, 2.3865, 1.976, 2.3085, 3.1135, 3.476, 
3.671, 2.1465, 3.0125, 2.129, 1.8335, 0.689, 0.8775, 1, 1.616, 
1.618, 2.5385, 1.9465, 1.799, 1.194, 0.7295, 0.7425, 0.5895, 
131.85), AP2D006 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 3.64, 2.972, 1.402, 1.421, 
1.622, 1.648, 2.379, 2.014, 2.182, 0.802, 1.812, 1.139, 1.042, 
1.5435, 2.097, 2.064, 1.205, 1.955, 1.2985, 1.6255, 1.697, 2.3645, 
2.6805, 2.2965, 2.3095, 2.082, 2.4395, 1.863, 1.879, 2.2505, 
2.648, 2.5805, 2.6895, 2.587, 3.393, 3.1505, 3.543, 2.765, 0.7355, 
0.508, 0.5035, 0.681, 1.0305, 1.308, 1.966, 2.32, 1.814, 2.847, 
2.5295, 1.262, 2.058, 1.5235, 2.1625, 2.1215, 1.3525, 1.368, 
1.574, 2.1725, 2.8545, 2.219, 1.717, 2.0185, 1.128, 1.1475, 0.591, 
0.4725, 0.44, 0.485, 0.5375, 0.5215, 0.5845, 0.565, 0.5065, 0.367, 
0.353, 0.2545, 121.5), AP2D009 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1.485, 1.695, 1.655, 
1.1835, 1.324, 1.0755, 0.7495, 1.014, 1.2435, 1.841, 1.8845, 
1.148, 1.066, 1.926, 2.5395, 1.5005, 1.59, 1.3565, 1.5405, 1.7205, 
1.5825, 1.245, 1.883, 1.907, 2.149, 1.512, 0.8935, 0.6925, 0.687, 
1.265, 1.5055, 0.4295, 0.3495, 0.4275, 0.4615, 0.5665, 0.4045, 
0.309, 0.187, 0.2205, 0.2705, 0.6155, 0.9485, 0.977, 0.7205, 
1.3575, 1.4925, 1.43, 1.1535, 1.3195, 1.184, 1.1885, 0.5415, 
0.7375, 0.7455, 1.08, 1.2335, 1.269, 1.1135, 1.193, 0.535, 0.4935, 
0.349, 0.2665, 71.1), AP2D101 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 2.549, 1.393, 1.54, 
1.821, 1.65, 1.357, 1.742, 1.629, 2.11, 2.11, 1.972, 1.58, 1.88, 
1.9745, 1.3035, 1.0575, 1.5935, 1.6695, 1.4555, 2.306, 2.4825, 
2.1905, 3.2565, 3.599, 3.058, 1.5925, 0.8025, 0.4385, 0.514, 
0.6395, 0.581, 0.476, 0.5115, 0.864, 1.348, 0.6565, 0.3845, 0.35, 
0.2895, 0.4045, 0.471, 0.2795, 0.365, 0.256, 0.2685, 0.444, 0.329, 
0.1945, 0.1995, 0.307, 0.28, 0.1935, 0.1925, 0.176, 0.156, 0.1955, 
0.1915, 0.2485, 0.236, 0.192, 0.1785, 0.1745, NaN, 77.85), AP2D102 = c(NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, 1.083, 0.596, 0.8295, 0.341, 0.302, 0.1795, 0.3505, 0.2935, 
0.792, 0.796, 0.794, 0.5485, 0.6185, 1.1145, 0.6725, 0.542, 0.5935, 
0.92, 1.058, 1.3855, 1.089, 1.1255, 1.5755, 1.096, 0.865, 0.771, 
0.359, 0.5065, 0.6805, 1.011, 0.6695, 0.916, 0.9635, 0.997, 1.223, 
1.2305, 0.549, 0.5075, 0.3985, 0.6935, 0.8915, 0.592, 1.0005, 
0.9545, 1.0675, 1.0905, 1.3205, 0.849, 0.9155, 0.759, 1.131, 
0.545, 0.6075, 0.696, 0.7745, 0.707, 1.095, 1.081, 1.0935, 0.771, 
0.407, 0.417, 0.2815, 58.05), AP2D103 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1.89, 0.637, 0.655, 0.728, 0.496, 0.6405, 
0.647, 0.519, 0.5245, 0.784, 0.5065, 0.3155, 0.888, 1.29, 1.078, 
2.117, 1.9445, 0.537, 1.483, 0.72, 1.4035, 1.875, 1.5105, 1.917, 
2.2765, 3.26, 4.4505, 2.934, 2.176, 3.1805, 3.9025, 2.613, 0.704, 
1.123, 0.8075, 1.241, 1.146, 1.3415, 0.9385, 1.264, 0.9355, 0.5185, 
0.515, 0.3635, 67.05), AP3B012 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.384, 1.387, 0.913, 2.094, 1.9315, 1.6805, 
1.786, 1.9035, 0.9345, 1.1825, 0.745, 0.402, 0.4425, 1.06, 0.796, 
0.865, 2.0025, 1.217, 2.362, 2.5695, 2.6205, 2.046, 2.886, 1.7505, 
3.9255, 2.385, 3.291, 1.9035, 3.952, 0.9955, 1.1625, 0.8605, 
0.5925, 0.894, 0.645, 0.808, 0.848, 1.126, 0.9, 0.842, 1.3375, 
0.987, 0.715, 1.0145, 1.181, 1.282, 0.781, 1.0705, 1.198, 1.1105, 
1.361, 1.523, 1.367, 2.099, 1.632, 1.482, 1.109, 0.915, 0.7505, 
1.041, 1.362, 1.2815, 1.452, 0.8735, 0.7945, 1.4145, 1.053, 0.604, 
0.496, 0.5095, 0.6825, 0.692, 0.765, 0.8125, 0.6225, 0.704, 0.8455, 
0.8555, 0.9605, 1.374, 0.9885, 1.0875, 0.818, 0.608, 0.3745, 
0.477, 0.493, 0.389, 0.5445, 0.5195, 0.416, 0.3045, 0.388, 0.475, 
117.45), AP3C003 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.864, 1.303, 1.526, 1.755, 
1.6755, 1.966, 0.9955, 1.826, 2.419, 1.3455, 2.674, 1.2985, 1.136, 
1.2045, 1.4395, 1.207, 1.6155, 0.747, 0.3255, 0.5825, 0.6715, 
0.7875, 0.5075, 0.7915, 0.6295, 1.0015, 1.0655, 0.791, 0.7365, 
0.811, 0.8255, 0.976, 0.886, 0.742, 0.6495, 1.174, 0.7135, 0.5695, 
0.4335, 0.403, 0.7665, 0.7705, 0.7535, 0.7935, 0.816, 0.648, 
0.609, 0.804, 0.868, 0.6895, 0.633, 0.8025, 0.952, 0.5745, 0.7275, 
0.9395, 0.9125, 1.1655, 1.1725, 1.167, 1.716, 1.7405, 0.899, 
0.689, 1.2195, 0.566, 1.056, 1.3895, 1.5445, 1.6875, 0.9655, 
0.738, 0.9635, 1.0905, 0.5625, 0.555, 0.499, 0.723, 1.0425, 1.143, 
0.9495, 0.991, 1.1495, 1.119, 1.637, 1.4185, 1.8495, 1.617, 1.5595, 
0.8665, 0.693, 0.5455, 0.4755, 0.4495, 0.4355, 0.461, 0.437, 
0.4485, 0.3075, 0.4915, 0.324, 97.2), AP3C004 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1.213, 2.051, 1.9785, 2.014, 
1.8175, 1.521, 1.41, 1.6, 1.1845, 1.523, 0.7555, 0.49, 0.3245, 
0.3685, 0.396, 0.386, 0.6635, 0.7135, 1.3875, 1.303, 0.6915, 
1.26, 1.047, 1.717, 2.556, 1.3405, 1.8075, 1.1115, 1.9395, 0.956, 
1.2815, 1.182, 0.986, 1.3365, 0.85, 1.133, 1.2705, 1.44, 1.1495, 
0.9655, 1.019, 1.1335, 0.8955, 1.0525, 0.9475, 0.777, 0.5705, 
0.841, 0.7975, 0.8365, 0.997, 0.8865, 1.072, 1.1055, 1.1845, 
0.769, 0.713, 0.423, 0.557, 0.5115, 0.616, 0.591, 0.8395, 0.834, 
0.603, 1.0795, 0.8225, 0.6915, 0.389, 0.587, 0.599, 0.678, 0.541, 
0.724, 0.8325, 0.929, 0.955, 1.341, 1.2635, 1.265, 1.1235, 1.29, 
0.889, 0.901, 0.589, 0.5495, 1.116, 0.945, 1.084, 1.097, 0.9305, 
0.636, 1.1145, 1.0885, 107.55), AP3C006 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 2.192, 1.629, 1.7385, 1.529, 
1.0845, 1.385, 2.1, 1.262, 1.6985, 1.178, 0.4605, 0.246, 0.395, 
0.3085, 0.3435, 0.4205, 0.3575, 0.6065, 0.845, 0.7185, 0.4835, 
0.374, 0.841, 1.1355, 0.88, 1.6065, 0.938, 1.951, 1.294, 1.1305, 
0.6615, 0.532, 0.991, 0.7385, 0.72, 0.6515, 1.016, 0.701, 0.649, 
0.745, 1.064, 0.8215, 0.7775, 0.7215, 0.6425, 0.531, 0.715, 0.5485, 
0.5125, 0.535, 0.556, 0.646, 0.761, 0.8585, 0.502, 0.433, 0.3585, 
0.288, 0.3925, 0.4115, 0.4905, 0.5765, 0.3925, 0.296, 0.447, 
0.466, 0.355, 0.2435, 0.203, 0.2455, 0.276, 0.2345, 0.241, 0.262, 
0.2295, 0.2775, 0.367, 0.4045, 0.3855, 0.436, 0.486, 0.391, 0.331, 
0.2745, 0.202, 0.2225, 0.252, 0.142, 0.161, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
71.55), AP3C007 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
0.309, 1.271, 1.951, 1.188, 1.279, 0.993, 0.712, 0.751, 1.01, 
0.9855, 1.1135, 1.0285, 0.8715, 0.491, 0.6965, 0.712, 0.564, 
0.761, 0.5115, 0.9185, 1.415, 0.668, 0.915, 0.561, 1.469, 1.8795, 
1.6, 2.2705, 1.307, 2.2295, 1.7, 0.7895, 0.5585, 0.4355, 0.6825, 
0.7255, 0.8215, 0.977, 0.8305, 0.658, 0.763, 0.776, 0.569, 0.4475, 
0.4725, 0.7665, 0.632, 0.5215, 0.6645, 0.7025, 0.7235, 0.872, 
0.6635, 0.8305, 1.112, 0.9745, 0.6345, 0.605, 0.325, 0.333, 0.489, 
0.4165, 0.5165, 0.681, 0.63, 0.494, 0.633, 0.5205, 0.3675, 0.3925, 
0.357, 0.3945, 0.355, 0.3895, 0.522, 0.4945, 0.4045, 0.4335, 
0.5165, 0.534, 0.703, 0.6705, 0.902, 0.5525, 0.499, 0.298, 0.2415, 
0.1995, 0.217, 0.2215, 0.2945, 0.3755, 0.2775, 0.299, 0.243, 
74.7), AP3C009 = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1.27, 1.569, 
1.835, 0.497, 0.868, 1.247, 0.8285, 1.2515, 0.933, 0.9325, 0.89, 
1.053, 1.1155, 1.534, 1.1725, 0.509, 0.453, 0.669, 0.6005, 0.4645, 
0.764, 0.9665, 1.6815, 2.199, 1.459, 1.819, 1.3145, 1.6195, 2.505, 
2.5875, 3.046, 2.106, 3.367, 1.8815, 2.1315, 1.559, 1.3835, 2.3815, 
1.894, 2.088, 2.3115, 2.7445, 2.0005, 1.383, 1.92, 2.1055, 1.532, 
1.6305, 2.055, 1.7215, 1.4205, 1.4015, 1.459, 1.53, 2.0205, 1.496, 
1.362, 1.923, 1.9535, 1.4275, 1.0955, 0.6085, 0.5295, 0.634, 
0.9845, 1.1095, 1.4335, 0.6545, 0.5525, 0.842, 0.949, 0.5215, 
0.3105, 0.311, 0.4625, 0.4255, 0.326, 0.419, 0.318, 0.336, 0.456, 
0.502, 0.69, 0.953, 0.5705, 0.913, 0.5185, 0.5145, 0.3585, 0.2685, 
0.334, 0.2435, 0.3295, 0.32, 0.32, 0.225, 0.268, 0.1815, 116.1
)), .Names = c("AP2D005", "AP2D006", "AP2D009", "AP2D101", "AP2D102", 
"AP2D103", "AP3B012", "AP3C003", "AP3C004", "AP3C006", "AP3C007", 
"AP3C009"), row.names = c("1909", "1910", "1911", "1912", "1913", 
"1914", "1915", "1916", "1917", "1918", "1919", "1920", "1921", 
"1922", "1923", "1924", "1925", "1926", "1927", "1928", "1929", 
"1930", "1931", "1932", "1933", "1934", "1935", "1936", "1937", 
"1938", "1939", "1940", "1941", "1942", "1943", "1944", "1945", 
"1946", "1947", "1948", "1949", "1950", "1951", "1952", "1953", 
"1954", "1955", "1956", "1957", "1958", "1959", "1960", "1961", 
"1962", "1963", "1964", "1965", "1966", "1967", "1968", "1969", 
"1970", "1971", "1972", "1973", "1974", "1975", "1976", "1977", 
"1978", "1979", "1980", "1981", "1982", "1983", "1984", "1985", 
"1986", "1987", "1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", 
"1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", 
"2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", 
"2010", "2011", "2012", "RBHinBarkmm"), class = "data.frame")
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: it looks like you could just keep track of the NA/NaNs from the start, let your function run, and then replace the values with NA/NaN at the end

Comment: This is a VERY small sample of my data.frame. I have hundreds of columns and hundreds of rows. Unfortunately tracking the NA values would prove difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this does what you descibe

```
cumsum.alt<-function(x) {
    rh <- x[length(x)]
    rx <- rev(x)[-1]
    r <- rep(NA, length(x))
    dx <- rh-cumsum(c(0,rx[!is.na(rx)]))
    r[c(!is.na(rx), FALSE)] <- dx[-length(dx)]
    r[max(which(!is.na(r)))+1] <- dx[length(dx)]
    rev(r)
}

cumsum.alt(c(1,2,3,NA,50))
# [1] 44 45 47 50 NA
cumsum.alt(c(NA,1,2,3,50))
# [1] NA 44 45 47 50
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried this with the data.frame, and it works partially but not completely. Basically the RBH value (the final row in df2) should become the final measurement for each column in df3, in the year where measurements end in df2 (this is variable, it could be 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, or 2012). Then the measurement from df2 (2010 is 1.8 in my initial example above) should be subtracted from the df2 RBH value (now 2010 in df3) to get the 2009 value in df3 (58.7 in the example above).

Comment: The new data.frame should actually have 1 additional row than the starting data.frame.

Comment: I've updated the code. Since you aren't returning the RBH row, the vector length going in should still be the same coming out after adding the earlier row, right?

Comment: Thanks for the update. You're correct, the vector length should be the same; I forgot the RBH row wasn't returned.

Also, one last question. I've tried running your function, and it works great for the 2 quick samples you gave. But I'm still pretty new to R and can't figure out how to apply the function to the data.frame as a whole, rather than just a list. How would I apply it for a data.frame? I've tried the following 2 options but neither returned the correct output:

`df3 <- cumsum.alt(df2)`

`df3 <- cumsum.alt(as.data.frame(df2))`

Comment: One way is `df3<-data.frame(lapply(df2, cumsum.alt))`

Comment: Thanks! I just figured it out at the same time! I used:

`df3 <- apply(df2, 2, function(x) cumsum.alt(x))` which I think should work the same.

You've solved a 4-day struggle; I really appreciate it!

Comment: With columns you should be OK. But in general i suggest you do not use `apply()` with data.frames; it's really better for matrices. One of the other *apply functions is usually more appropriate for data.frames.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly.  It's just a cumsum that fills in NA entries with NA instead of the previous known value, right?

```
cumsum.alt <- function(x){
  res <- rep(NA,length(x))
  sumtohere <- 0
  for(i in seq(x)){
    if (!is.na(x[i])){
      sumtohere <- sumtohere+x[i]
      res[i] <- sumtohere
    } else {
      res[i] <- NA 
    }  
  }  
  res
}
```

What's this talk about needing the last row to have a value?  All these example last rows have values.  If it's NA, what should it be filled with?

Comment: Basically everything in df3 has shifted by 1 year: the final row should be equal to the RBH value from df2, so long as there were no NA values in df2. If a sample has a value of 2.3 for 2012 in df2 and an RBH of 60, then in the new data.frame (df3) the sample was 60 cm in 2012 when last measured, and was 57.7 cm in 2011 (RBH-2012 from df2). Does that help fix the confusion, or make it worse? Additionally, if a sample only has measurements to 2010, then in the new data.frame (df3) 2010 should equal the RBH value from df2, and 2009 should equal the RBH value - the 2010 value in df2.